# How do i run a TF-IDF in python on a single column from a big data set (csv file)?

Tags: python, tf-idf

I am attempting to create a python program that runs the TF-IDF of a big data set. It has multiple columns and several rows of data. My problem is I don't know how to limit it to only run on one of the columns titled Comments.

Answer (score 0):

You can take out the values of required column and run TF-IDF on it:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

doc=df['Comments'].values #df is your dataframe
tf = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english')
tfidf_matrix = tf.fit_transform(doc)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I received an error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn.feature_extraction.txt'.  Where do I get this module from?

Comment: you can install using `pip` `pip install scikit-learn`. Please follow here : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/install.html